# Can I assign a numpy array to new columns in pandas 1.0.3

Tags: python, pandas

This bit of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5))
df[['A', 'B']] = np.arange(30,40).reshape(5,2)
```

Works fine in 1.1.1 but throws an error in 1.0.3

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Is there a way to do this in a backwards compatible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `T` to transpose the array and use unpacking:

```
df['A'], df['B'] = np.arange(30,40).reshape(5,2).T
```

Result:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   A   B
0   0   1   2   3   4  30  31
1   5   6   7   8   9  32  33
2  10  11  12  13  14  34  35
3  15  16  17  18  19  36  37
4  20  21  22  23  24  38  39
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `assign`

```
df=df.assign(**dict(zip(['A', 'B'], np.arange(30,40).reshape(2,5))))
Out[119]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   A   B
0   0   1   2   3   4  30  35
1   5   6   7   8   9  31  36
2  10  11  12  13  14  32  37
3  15  16  17  18  19  33  38
4  20  21  22  23  24  34  39
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm certainly glad they made it easier now.